# How can I copy the last updated time from one set of files to another?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have two directories:

```
/dev/
/www/
```

The www is a copy of the dev directory.I copy the files across from the dev to the www when they're ready to go live by a script which deletes all of the files inside the www directory and then copies the dev files to it. I'm losing the updated time though as the new copies are essentially new files.

How can I copy the last-modified date too?

Answer (score 1):

It was only a particular subdirectory that I was concerned about so I did it with a for loop in my shell script.

```
$DIR_DEV="/dev"
$DIR_LIVE="/www"

for i in  `ls $DIR_DEV/demos/*.html`
do
    DEMO_FILENAME=`basename $i`
    touch -d `stat $DIR_DEV/demos/$DEMO_FILENAME --format=%y` "$DIR_LIVE/demos/$DEMO_FILENAME"
done
```

OOPSY: As I write this I've realised that the copy command has a --preserve option... Could've saved a few hours. :-/